# In a tennis scoring program, what would be a good approach for storing and presenting both standard games and tiebreaks?

Tags: design

In a tennis match, each game has the possible scores of Love, 15, 30, 40, or Advantage. This could be modeled as a dictionary `[0: "Love", 1: "15", 2: "30", 3: "40", 4: "Advantage"]` or enumerated type cases. In the situation where both players win six games however, the next game is a tiebreak where points are simply scored as 0, 1, 2, etc where the first to 7 with a margin of 2 wins the game. What would be a good approach for taking into account both in scoring?

Comment: Maybe keep state of the match and choose a different strategy for scoring?

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand without knowing Tennis scoring, I would suggest to explain the scoring in more detail or add a link.

Comment: Having "Advantage" as the same level as "15" does not seem useful to me. You can have a score of "15:40", but you cannot have "Advantage:40".

Answer (score -1):

Enums are discrete values that are not continuous. For example, in "book", "magazine" and "CD", book +1 is not magazine. However, your scores are continuous, when one player scores, it increases. So I would see this as game type A goes to 5 and game type B goes to 7. The only thing that needs to be polymorph is the visual representation to the user.

You can parameterize a class

```
class game {
    void game(int winningScore, int leadRequired, Dictionary<int, string> visualScoreRepresentation)
    { ... }
}
```

you can subclass ...

```
abstract class game {
     string getScore(int score);
}

class TieBreaker : game
{
    static Dictionary<int, string> scoreMap = new Dictionary<int, string scoreMap>
    {
        { 0, "Love" }
    };
    override string getScore(int score)
    {
          return scoreMap[score];
    }
}
```

Comment: Tennis score is discrete, not continuous.

Comment: the idea here is that you can model it as continous.